# removeChild not working despite calling from parent

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm having a problem with the `removeChild` method. The browser is giving me a type error.

Here's my code:

HTML

```
<header>
    <div id="header-div">
        <img id="logo-image" src="img.jpg" alt="image">
    </div>
    <div class="mobile-hamburger">
        <a href="#menu" class="box-shadow-menu">text</a>
    </div>
</header>
```

JS

```
var windowWidth = parseInt(window.innerWidth);

if (windowWidth >= 700) {

let headerTag = document.getElementsByTagName("header");
let hamburgerMenu = document.getElementsByClassName("mobile-hamburger");

hamburgerMenu.headerTag.removeChild(hamburgerMenu);

}
```

I'm testing it when window width is 1920px. I can also see that browser grabs `<header>` tag and `<div>` with `"mobile-hamburger"` class at debugging tool. So they are fine.

I can't find the problem with `removeChild` line here. I'm removing an element after calling its parent.

Here's a jsfiddle with this code: https://jsfiddle.net/u3r9m5f0/

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection. Use a loop.

Comment: Not sure what you were hoping for with `hamburgerMenu.headerTag`. The `headerTag` is a variable, which is also a collection and is unrelated to the `hamburgerMenu` collection.

Comment: Just FYI, there is no reason to use JS for this functionality - you can just do it in simple CSS.

Comment: @junkfoodjunkie Thanks for the constructive comment. I know I can just set it to 'display:none' and get on with it at various renditions, but I want to practice on my poor Javascript skills(see above) :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementsByTagName` and `document.getElementsByClassName` return node lists which are array like objects. You need to get the element at the first index.

You also have the syntax for `parent.removeChild(child)` incorrect

```
var windowWidth = parseInt(window.innerWidth);

if (windowWidth >= 700) {

  let headerTag = document.getElementsByTagName("header")[0];
  let hamburgerMenu = document.getElementsByClassName("mobile-hamburger")[0];

  headerTag.removeChild(hamburgerMenu);

}
```

Comment: @Eorekan: If you only want the first element, you can use `querySelector`. And you don't need to fetch the parent separately, since you can use `.parentNode` from the child. `var hm = document.querySelector(".mobile-hamburger"); hm.parentNode.removeChild(hm);`

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array even it contains one element so use `getElementsByClassName[0]`
 to select the first occurrence (the only one  in this case )

Same applies to `getElementsbyTagName`